# PHP __FILE__ returns backslashes in Linux VM file mounted from OSX Host

Tags: php, linux, macos, configuration, kohana

I run LAMP in Fedora VM from OSX (Mavericks) host.

the file in VM mounted folder is /media/sf_www/application/Some/Name/Space/FileName.php

```
<?php 
namespace Some\Name\Space;

die(__FILE__);
?>
```

outputs

/media/sf_www/application/Some\Name\Space\FileName.php

However, I have same site running in production on linux host and the same script outputs everything with forward slashes.

Let's assume I cannot touch the code.

Is there anything in php configuration I can do on my vm to output forward slashes?

Why is this happening? OSX should use forward slashes too, even if it takes directory separator from a VM Hosting machine.

Edit:
This happens only when the file is loaded via Kohana. If I access script directly  (apache or CLI), the output is correct (forward slashes)

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of related question: [PHP directory separators, forcing forward slash; non-intrusive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162042/php-directory-separators-forcing-forward-slash-non-intrusive)

The answer that it gives is, no there is no configuration that you change to make it use just the one type of slash.

Why it is happening?  I have no idea, maybe it is a quasi-bug in Kohana. And maybe in part the fault of PHP because the function that joins paths together is a little too agnostic about what kind of slash it accepts.

Is there a reason that this should matter?  If you must have one kind of slash you can just do `str_replace('\\', '/', __FILE__);` to it first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have this running correctly natively on  a linux machine. So, it suggests that  it could run correct somehow. Now I have to figure out if it is because the files are sitting in vm host osx and mounted only on linux and kohana cannot figure it out, or is it some php configuration that does not work with Kohana. At this point I try not to touch the code as It would be the entire code base "search and fix".

Comment: It could also suggest that somewhere kohana is doing some OS detection to decide what kind of slash to use, and not taking into account the possibility of it being OSX.  Also if you explain why it matters, a good workaround might be able to be suggested.

Comment: Kohana does figure out if it is windows or not. And i can confirm that it sets this system to be not windows. I just wonder what kind of code can overwrite __FILE__ behavior. I did find all the ini_set usages and did not see anything weird there. Also I was thinking it has to do something with namespaces, as it returns backslashes only between namespace path parts. 
There are many intrusive workarounds. But I need not intrusive as I have very limited testing of the web app.

Comment: If your looking for non intrusive, look at the other post I linked to, the answer is that there is none.  The question I would like know is why it matters?  It might be easer to solve that.

Comment: It matters because It uses it for loading the file through  `include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../../Blah.php")`. I tried fixing it with str replace, but then other file craps out that uses the same code.. and then there is a whole bunch of them. So the wisest solution would be to figure out the difference between working and non working environments and eliminate it.

Comment: Ok, My solution was to keep code in vm and mount a folder from vm to my host (osx) machine via macfussion.